# How to setup Leiningen/ClojureScript compiler to support user scripts?

Tags: build, clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

User scripts require to start with a [metadata block](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block). How one can setup Leiningen and/or ClojureScript compiler to insert predefined metablock from e.g. a text file?

I have tried following:

```
; test
;; test 2
(comment test 3)
```

but it got stripped (probably because `{:optimizations :advanced}`?).

Please try to explain and describe your answers well, I am a total noob in Clojure and know almost nothing about Leiningen (I managed to get a simple ClojureScript build functional, but that's about it - I wanted to start learning Clojure by writing simple user scripts which I may actually use).

Comment: My guess here is, that this would have to be supported in cljs/closure.  If that is just a "text block" on the beginning of the generated file, i'd just do a `cat metadata compiled.js > metadata.js` step after compilation.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it supports it directly. I have no clue about Leiningen and whether it supports some kind of after compilation hooks (also since the build file is in Clojure, it's kinda hard for me, because I want this project to use for learning Clojure). I didn't want to go witch hacky solutions like a script in bash calling Leiningen and then manipulating resulting file - it feels wrong, IMO it should be handled by the build tool (at least that's the recommended way in other build tools I used so far).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:preamble` option to prepend the output files with a block of data.  You can see the compiler option [here](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#libs) (scroll down just a bit... the link to the preamble section doesn't work because there's another div that has the preamble id).

For reference, here's the documentation:

> `:preamble`
>
> Prepends the contents of the given files to each output file. Only
>   valid with optimizations other than `:none`.
>
> Defaults to the empty vector `[]`
>
> ```
> :preamble ["license.js"]
> ```

Comment: This looks promising, sadly I don't know how to use it - https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/issues/472.

Comment: The `"license.js"` file needs to live in a resources folder.  I forget what the default is in Leiningen (`"src/main/clojure"` or `"src/main/cljs"`, I think), but you can setup one using the [`:resource-paths` option](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L303) in Leiningen.  I just tried it out on one of my projects and it worked as expected.